# Python scrapy Crawling the links not scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy Framework and trying to learn web scraping 
i have a txt file with website pages links and i am making a list of those links and storing them in ***start_urls*** but but the parse function not working and it is not scraping anything

here is the code

```
try:
    import scrapy
except ImportError:
    print "\nERROR IMPORTING THE NESSASARY LIBRARIES\n"

#File with all the links
crimefile = open('links.txt', 'r')
#making a list with all the links
yourResult = [line for line in crimefile.readlines()]

class SpiderMan(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'man spider'

    #making start_urls equal to that list
    start_urls = yourResult

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.c411Listing.jsResultsList'
        for man in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            name = '.c411ListedName a ::text'
            address = '.adr ::text'
            phone = '.c411Phone ::text'
            yield { 

                    'NAME': man.css(name).extract_first(),
                    'ADDRESS': man.css(address).extract_first(),
                    'PHONE': man.css(phone).extract_first(),
                    }
```

ad [image: here] is the output it is for some reason the parse function is not working but scraping is crawling each link

What am i doing wrong ? in this simple code ?

Comment: In scrapy shell i got results, have you tried debugging. how are you running scrapy?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your urls are ending with "%0D%0A". If you enter one of the URLs from the scrapy log into a browser you will get a screen stating:

"Postal code entered is of wrong format."

The "%0D%0A" are the line breaks in your file of URLs that are somehow kept while loading the file and splitting it in lines. Remove them and you'll be fine.

Easy fix - add a call to strip():

```
yourResult = [line.strip() for line in crimefile.readlines()]
```

Comment: i have a huge list and the for loop is not striping for all elements

Comment: If `strip()` is not working for all elements there might also be other characters invalidating the URLs. Check for quotes, strange unicode characters, unicode whitespaces. These need to be removed, too. If that doesn't help, post some examples of urls that don't work here (copy them from the log).

Comment: thanks but i have checked all urls were special characters free but for some reason it could only work with 1000 links at a time, for other links scrapy was not visiting. So i did a quick fix i created a loop to get 1000 links from the text file at a time and used your corrected code. I would really like to know what caused this behaviour maybe some limitation of scrapy.

Comment: Scrapy itself doesn't have such limitation. As long as there is sufficient memory it will even process millions of start urls. So the problem must be somewhere else. Didn't scrapy even mention these urls in the log?